# using JointState.position in transformations

Tags: ros, forward-kinematics, position, ros-indigo, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Can I directly use the joinstate.position[i] for rotation or should there be some processing when rotating successive joints other than the first one?
This is with reference to forward kinematics on ROS indigo.

Thanks.

http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272898/using-jointstate.position-in-transformations/) by [imaminion](https://answers.ros.org/users/32224/imaminion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
I'm not sure I completely understand what you are asking. Can you clarify what you mean with "some processing when rotating successive joints other than the first one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got an answer. My questions was if position[i] represented the angle of rotation or the difference in angle with respect to the previous rotation position[i - 1].
The answer is, position[i] refers to the actual rotation angle.
Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [imaminion](https://answers.ros.org/users/32224/imaminion/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0